# How can I add ng-model to a Custom Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

What am I doing wrong here? In Angular JS, I am trying to add a ng-model name to a custom directive so it binds with the parent scope. I want it to look something like this:

```
   <div use-date-picker this-ngmodel="something"></div>
    The ng model: {{ something }}
```

I tried this in the directive but the ng-model name that I want to pass via attribute is not adding that to the template:

```
app.directive('useDatePicker', function() { 

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            thisNgmodel: '=',
            //bindAttr: '='
        },      
        template: '<div class="input-group">' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" name="dt" ng-model=thisNgmodel is-open="datepickers.dt" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />' +
                    '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,\'dt\')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>' +
                    '</span>' +
                   '</div>   ',        


    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need quotes around ng-model="thisNgModel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing double quotes around the `ng-model` in your template:

`ng-model=thisNgmodel` Should be `ng-model="thisNgmodel"`

**Example of** `ng-init`:

```
<div use-date-picker ng-init="something = 1" this-ngmodel="something"></div>
```

**Example of passing string to directive:**
To pass a string variable to your directive use the `@` sign.

```
<div use-date-picker string-var="test"></div>

scope: {
    stringVar: '@'
},
template: '<input type="text" value="{{stringVar}}" />'
```

Now you will be able to pass a string value to your directive and the `value` attribute on your input will default in with that text. It makes more sense to bind a property to your text box through `ng-model` though so you can retrieve its value later. By initializing your `ng-model` value as seen in the previous example you will achieve the same effect.

Comment: Add a `link` function to your directive. Then log the value of `scope.thisNgmodel` in that to make sure you are getting a value.

Comment: I added this not sure if this is the correct way to add link (sorry its my first directive): `link: function(scope, element, atr) {
   console.log('thisNgmodel');
  }`

Comment: change your `console.log('thisNgmodel)` to be `console.log(scope.thisNgmodel)`;

Comment: Thankx for that. I tried that and the console is now showing as `undefined`

Comment: OK, so your `something` variable has not been defined yet. Give it a default value in your controller or use `ng-init` to set its value in the template and it should work.

Comment: I am a bit confused. `something` is the name I want to give to that ng-model and not a variable. I apologise if I misunderstood what you said.

Comment: `ngModel` is used for binding scope properties not strings. You can't pass it an undefined variable. If you add an `ng-init="something = 1"` to your div you will now have a new variable called `something` on your scope and the `ng-model` binding will show `1` in your directives text box. To pass a string to your directive you would need to use `@` instead of `=` in your isolated scope and bind to the value of the text box instead of `ng-model`

Comment: Thank you @DiscoGolfer. Its making sense now. :)

Comment: Sorry... If I am not asking for too much, would you be able to show me an example for: "To pass a string to your directive you would need to use @ instead of = in your isolated scope and bind to the value of the text box instead of ng-model"